# How to run script from root as another user (with user PATH)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash

I would like to have these commands run as the `ss` user from `root`

```
mkdir bin
cp -r /opt/gitolite .
gitolite/install -ln
gitolite setup -pk ss.pub

mkdir -p .gitolite/hooks/common
ln -s /opt/pre-receive .gitolite/hooks/common/
```

so everything is executed in `/home/ss`. The 4th line requires `$HOME/bin` as you can see from the 3rd line.

The only way I can get it to work is by adding `su -c "command" ss` to each line, which is not a nice hack.

This is an extension to my previous [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/444626/possible-to-ignore-the-users-shell-in-su-command), where I wasn't precise enough.

**Question**

How do I run all these commands as a script in a practical way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you make it an actual executable script and call the script while running as the other user via `su`

Answer (score 6):

A shell script is exactly that, a shell script. Meaning that not only can you run normal shell commands, but you can also execute the built-ins for whatever shell you're using. We could slightly modify your script thusly to have all the commands run as if in the home directory of whatever user runs this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME
mkdir bin
cp -r /opt/gitolite .
gitolite/install -ln
gitolite setup -pk ss.pub

mkdir -p .gitolite/hooks/common
ln -s /opt/pre-receive .gitolite/hooks/common/
```

Comment: WHERE IS THE SHEBANG, YOU SAVAGE.

Comment: @MDMarra: In related news, after typing in the shebang line I hit <ESC>: before realizing what I was doing. Talk about muscle memory.